# Django GenericRelation for the update_or_create

Tags: python, django, generic-foreign-key

I have an issue with using `GenericRelation` with `update_or_create`.
I have the following models:

```
class LockCode(TimeStampedModel):
    context_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    context_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    context = GenericForeignKey('context_type', 'context_id')


class Mission(DirtyFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    lock_codes = GenericRelation(
        LockCode,
        content_type_field='context_type',
        object_id_field='context_id',
        related_query_name='mission'
    )
```

I try to create or update `LockCode` using the mission as a key:

```
mission = ....
LockCode.objects.update_or_create(
            context=mission,
            defaults={
             #some other columns there
            }
```

And I have the `FieldError: Field 'context' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.`

It works when I use the context_id and context_type explicitly:

```
LockCode.objects.update_or_create(
            context_id=mission.pk,
            context_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Mission),
            defaults={
             #some other columns there
            }
```

Is it something wrong in my configuration? Or it is only single way to use  `GenericForeignKey` for the update_or_create?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. Just need to use `mission` instead of `context` into update_or_create:

```
mission = ....
LockCode.objects.update_or_create(
            mission=mission,
            defaults={
             #some other columns there
            }
```

Comment: The above works only for the `update` :( For create it fails with `Mission is not iterable`.